# How to get enum by user defined name in java?

Tags: java

I am defined a enum in Java 8 like this:

```
public enum Cflb implements IBaseEnum {        
    没收违法所得("没收违法所得、没收非法财物", 2),
    暂扣或者吊销许可证("暂扣或者吊销许可证、暂扣或者吊销执照", 4);
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    Cflb(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }  
}
```

How to get enumn by "暂扣或者吊销许可证、暂扣或者吊销执照"? attention:not get the enumn by value. The code maybe like this:

```
Cflb cflb = getEnumnByInternalName("暂扣或者吊销许可证、暂扣或者吊销执照");
```

Comment: Loop through the enum elements until you find the one with the matching `name`.

Comment: By the way, it's unorthodox to have setters in an enum. Enums are generally expected to be fully constant.

Comment: What exactly is  `IBaseEnum`?  Is that a "real" Java enum? Or just a class that is called "enum"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over the enum constants using `values()` and compare the `name`:

```
static Cflb getEnumnByInternalName(String iname) {
  for(Cbfl c : values()){
    if(c.name.equals(iname)){
      return c;
    }
  }
  return null; //or throw an Exception, whatever you need
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Cflb cflb = Cflb.getEnumnByInternalName("暂扣或者吊销许可证、暂扣或者吊销执照");
```

And as @khelwood mention above: Remove the setters.

Comment: Thank you,I've solved the problem by your tips.@f1sh